# Way to connect to VPS w/Win Vista Home Basic, other than VNC or TeamViewer?

Tags: windows-vista, remote, desktop, teamviewer, vnc

I need to connect to a VPS and I'm running Vista Home Basic.  TightVNC and TeamViewer both require access to the VPS first, because they require that the server be set up with TightVNC or TeamViewer.

Is there anything similar to Remote Desktop that will allow me to use the IP address and administrator password to the VPS to simply connect, rather than having to have the hosting company set up VNC or TeamViewer on the server first?

Any help would be appreciated!!! Thank you!

Comment: What is the operating system on the server?

Comment: you should upgrade the OS to at least vista pro.  I'm not sure you can even legally run vista home as a VM

Answer (score 1):

Running a home edition of Windows in a hosted VM seems strange - I would expect a Server (or Pro/Business/Enterprise) edition which would allow you to connect and login via Remote Desktop.

VNC on its own is not recommended on the public network unless you are using a variant of VNC that has more security added, as otherwise all data including passwords is transmitted in plain. It is common to access VNC via a SSH tunnel or VPN to avoid this issue (though there are no doubt VNC variants which have better security built in). Also, if your Vista install has UAC turned on each UAC request will kick out your VNC session.

Unless by "with Vista Home" you mean your local machine runs Vista Home edition and there is something else on your server - in which case you need to tell us what OS installed on your VPS.

Comment: I got the impression from "I need to connect to a VPS and I'm running Vista Home Basic" that their desktop is vista and the server is something else. Bad wording though and as usual not enough info.

Comment: Yeah I read this as "I don't understand Linux command line and I need a remote desktop type thing". But I may be wrong.